# running python with sublime: dtype output is not stable

Tags: python, pandas, sublimetext3

I tried to run the following codes for several times. The output is sometimes 'True' (what I expected) and sometimes 'False'. Is there something wrong with sublime? I tested it with jupyter notebook and the output is always 'True'.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
print(df.dtypes.isin(['int64']))
```

if I print df.dtypes, the output is always 'int64'.

```
print(df.dtypes)
>> a    int64
   dtype: object
```

Python version: anaconda python3.6. Sublime version:3.1.1. pandas version: 0.23.4

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. Changing 'int64' to np.dtype('int64') seems to help. But in my jupyter notebook test, the return with isin(['int64']) is indeed 'True'. I don't know why. Maybe it's because of the versions of numpy are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of you example is not `True` it is `False`. If you do `df.dtypes.values` you will see it is not the string `'int64'` it is `dtype('int64')` so `isin(['int64'])` should always return `False` I tested in `Jupyter` and the ouput is always `False`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
print(df.dtypes.isin(['int64']))

a    False
dtype: bool

print(df.dtypes.values)
array([dtype('int64')], dtype=object)
```

The solution is to convert `df.dtypes` to a `str`:

```
df.dtypes.apply(str).values

array(['int64'], dtype=object)
```

so you can now do `isin`:

```
df.dtypes.apply(str).isin(['int64'])

a    True
dtype: bool
```